# Custom page breadcrumb name in magento

Tags: magento, path, label, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to change the breadcrumb that is showed on my blog page.
Now I have something like" Home / Blog ", but I want it to show like " Home / NewNameHere ".
I went to my blog.xml file and where I had this:

```
<blog_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="blog/blog" name="blog" template="blog/blog.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</blog_index_index>
```

Changed to this:

```
<blog_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="blog/blog" name="blog" template="blog/blog.phtml"/>
        <action method="addCrumb">
                         <name>newnamehere</name>
                         <params>
                                 <label>newnamehere</label>
                                 <title>newnamehere</title>
                                 <link> /blog/</link>
                         </params>
                 </action>
    </reference>
</blog_index_index>
```

But nothing has changed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
<blog_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="blog/blog" name="blog" template="blog/blog.phtml"/>
        <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs">
                <action method="addCrumb">
                   <name>NewName</name>
                   <params>
                   <label>NewName</label>
                   <title>NewName</title>
                   <link>/blog/</link>
                   </params>
                 </action>
            </block>
    </reference>
</blog_index_index>
```

And in your **blog.phtml** call like this

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->toHtml();?>
```